# Looking for children's comic board book about a detective w/ rebuses

Tags: story-identification, comics, childrens-novel

I remember reading a kids comic board book growing up. It was in the children's section in my local library.

**Some minor details about the content and physical nature of the book**

- The book was bound like the Tintin books and the same size.
- It was about some sort of space detective, looking for a missing person.
- The dialogue had a lot of rebuses and puns like "moons of mice/ice".
- They find the person in a pyramid.

After he solved the case, he gets a call about a missing space princess and runs off on another case.